# Using Page Object Model in React Native iOS

Tags: automated-testing, mobile-automation, reactjs

I am using react native with iOS. I have to build an automation framework.

I am wondering if it's possible to use Page Object Model?

I would like to because with would make the framework robust as any changes would be dealt with in 1 location rather that going into individual 'it scenarios' in each spec file to make modifications.

I am using grey box testing to do this.  Is it even possible in grey box?

If it is possible how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply abstract page components and behavior on an object, you are using the Page Object Model - do not get confused if you are dealing with "screens", not "pages"...

```
object = { button = () => find('button'), save = () => this.button().click() }
```

There are some libraries for Page Objects specifically for React.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-page-object

[image]